# Where to put drawable for 480x800 hdpi, mdpi, ldpi

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-screen-support, android-screen

I have a problem with different screen sizes and different density issues.
I am developing an app for different resolutions but for 480 x 800 resolution I am confused.

I have a single copy of images for 480 x 800. But in market there are different devices for this resolution. 
For Example:

1. 480 x 800 (hdpi) --> For phones
2. 480 x 800 (mdpi)
3. 480 x 800 (ldpi) ---> Tablets (7inch)

My confusion is , where should I put the images in which images so all above screen sizes can get these images.

**Edit:**

I am placing **hdpi images** in the drawable-hdpi and **mdpi and ldpi images** in drawable-sw480dp-mdpi folder. This is increasing the size of app because I am repeting same images in seperate folder.

**Edit**

Can Anybody provide the solution for my problem please?

Answer (score 0):

```
>xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
>large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
>normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
>small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is to use vector graphics for example .svg files. [link](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities)